# Building libspline for Matlab on Windows - ambiguous call to overloaded function 'pow'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matlab, overload-resolution

I'm trying to build libspline for Matlab on Windows, available here:

http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~smaji/projects/libspline-release1.0.tar.gz

I get the following error:

```
>> make
additiveModel.cpp 
additiveModel.cpp(156) : error C2668: 'pow' : ambiguous call to overloaded function 
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(583): could be 'long double pow(long double,int)' 
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(535): or       'float pow(float,int)' 
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(497): or       'double pow(double,int)' 
        while trying to match the argument list '(int, int)' 

  C:\USR\ML\MATLAB~1\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'additiveModel.cpp' failed. 

??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in ==> make at 4
mex -O -largeArrayDims -c additiveModel.cpp
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line 156 in `additiveModel.cpp` is this:

```
dimwts[2*i] = 1.0/pow(i+1,reg);
```

Here you can see that both of the arguments that are being passed to `pow` are `int`s. Since there is no overload of `pow` in `math.h` that would take two `int`s, the overload resolution fails since the *best viable function* is not unique in this case.

You can fix this by casting the first parameter to a suitable type, such as `double`:

```
dimwts[2*i] = 1.0/pow(static_cast<double>(i+1),reg);
```