# Pow: ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c, pow, math.h

I have problem , I can not find any solution.

It gives the same error:

> Pow: ambiguous call to overloaded function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() 
{
    int a, i, n, product, result=1;

    printf("enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("enter n number\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        product = pow(a, i);
        result *= product;
    }
    printf("the result is %d", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have to initialize `result=1` otherwise it will use garbage value

Comment: you compile as C++. change to C mode.

Comment: Would this help: [Building libspline for Matlab on Windows - ambiguous call to overloaded function 'pow'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633970/building-libspline-for-matlab-on-windows-ambiguous-call-to-overloaded-function)?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it did not work

Comment: @punitvara good point thanks but it did not work

Comment: I can compile with no error (there is warning. :D). Whether the program is working properly is another matter.

Comment: Selected C++ duplicate does not well explain the failure here.  Nominate for re-opening.

Comment: @chux Poor use of the dupe hammer in my view. The asker is actually compiling C++ and the dupe explains it perfectly.

Comment: @chux: agree with Devid Heffernan.  There are no overloads in C; the compiler cannot be a C compiler.  The duplicate question explains the issue nicely — the compiler messages in the question show that passing an `int` as the first argument to `pow()` in C++ leads to ambiguity because `int` has to be converted and can be converted to `float`, `double` or `long double` with equal facility, leading to the ambiguity.  The fact that people end up using a C++ compiler to compile C code is a separate source of exasperation — I assume they're confused by the IDE that they're using.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  If this post is viewed as tagged C, solutions include using type-generic math with `<tgmath.h>` with acts very similar to C++ overloads. I agree this is certainly OP using a C++ compiler on C code.  A user having problems with `pow()` and filtering on `C` will not find that duplicate as it is another language.  The candidate solutions in C differ from C++  and thus I still assert the claimed duped is a poor candidate.

Comment: @chux: we are going to have to agree to disagree.  If there was any sign of `#include <tgmath.h>` in the code I might be more sympathetic.  As it is, compiling code with a C++ compiler means you get C++ error messages for problems that only appear when you use a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler — regardless of why you are using the wrong compiler.

Comment: @David Heffernan How did you determine the original duplicate after the post was re-opened?

Comment: @chux You can see that in the edit history

Comment: @David Heffernan Thanks.  Concerning the [original duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17633970/2410359), that was a C++ one where the OP did not include `<math.h>` and so I disagree that [the dupe explains it perfectly.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378487/pow-ambiguous-call-to-overloaded-function?noredirect=1#comment56507783_34378487).  Perhaps you thought  that my vote was on another dupe?

Comment: @chux I honestly don't understand why you continue to assert that this is a C question. C does not have overloading. I'm sure you know this.

Comment: @David Heffernan This is a C question because the OP called it C, likely wanted it to be C and posted code has many hallmarks of good C (`.h, scanf(), printf()`) vs. C-ish C++.  OP's problem was likely not using a C compiler.  2) C _does_ have something very similar to overloading.  This is possible with `_Generic` and is purposely available with  `<tgmath.h>` which would make C source code `pow(float)` and `pow(double)` call different functions.  As OP's message is with `pow()`, that consideration is relevant.

Comment: @chux Like Jonathan, I disagree with you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98498/discussion-between-chux-and-david-heffernan).

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is uninitialized variables, namely `result` that doesn't have a valid value to be used in the line:

```
result *= product;
```

and then some implicit conversions in the use of function `pow()`. There isn't a overloaded `pow()` instance containing `int` and `int` as first and second parameter, and `int` as returning value.

You should consider defining your arguments appropriately according to function supported argument list, which in *C*, using header `math.h` is:

```
double pow(double x, double y)
```

otherwise you may suffer the consequences of sometimes producing unexpected results, as the compiler performs narrowing conversions implicitly. Check for the dangers of implicit conversions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279667.aspx).